# how to consume a restful webservice in oracle store procedure

Tags: oracle, web-services, rest

How do I consume a RESTful webservice in Oracle stored procedure? I am using Oracle 11C.

Any sample code or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It may help you : http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/consuming-web-services-9i.php

Comment: above link shows consuming SOAP webservices.. is there same avaialble for restful webservices

Comment: Here it is : http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_web_service-consuming-soap-and-rest-web-services.php#rest